# error when renewing my let's encrypt certificate

Tags: apache, https, certificate, lets-encrypt

whenever i try to renew my domain's certificate using cerbot I'm faced with an error message.

this a linux server running ubuntu and apache, the certificate was issued by certbot, the server doesn't have a control panel so everything is done using ssh.

the commandline response with error message at the bottom:

```
Attempting to parse the version 0.32.0 renewal configuration file found at /etc/letsencrypt/renewal/mydomin.com.conf with version 0.31.0 of Certbot.

This might not work.

Cert is due for renewal, auto-renewing...

Plugins selected: Authenticator webroot, Installer None

Renewing an existing certificate

Performing the following challenges:

http-01 challenge for mydomin.com

http-01 challenge for www.mydomin.com

Cleaning up challenges

Attempting to renew cert (mydomin.com) from /etc/letsencrypt/renewal
/mydomin.com.conf produced an unexpected error: Missing command line flag or config entry for this setting:

Input the webroot for mydomin.com:. Skipping.

All renewal attempts failed. The following certs could not be renewed:

  /etc/letsencrypt/live/mydomin.com/fullchain.pem (failure)
```

Answer (score 1):

Some answer you can found at [here](https://oprtr.org/letsencrypt-missing-command-line-flag-or-config-entry-for-this-setting/)

Quick check you certbot renewal config

Section [[webroot_map]] must be something like this

```
sub.domain.tld = /var/www/certbot
```